# css not working in jquery tabs system

Tags: jquery, html, css, tabs

i'm working on my site, and i am using tabs right now, the problem is with the css of it.

thats my jquery code:

```
$(function() {
$( "#tabs" ).tabs();

// fix the classes
$( ".tabs-bottom .ui-tabs-nav, .tabs-bottom .ui-tabs-nav > *" )
  .removeClass( "ui-corner-all ui-corner-top" )
  .addClass( "ui-corner-bottom" );

// move the nav to the bottom
$( ".tabs-bottom .ui-tabs-nav" ).appendTo( ".tabs-bottom" );
});
```

thats the css file:

```
    #box1 {
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    background: #FFFFFF url(images/homepage13.jpg) no-repeat left top;
}
#box1-ing {
    margin-bottom: 25px;
}
#box1-ing .content {
    padding: 17px;
    color: #4D5E5F;
}
#box1 .content {
    min-height: 110px;
    padding: 17px;
    background: url(images/homepage14.jpg) no-repeat right bottom;
    color: #4D5E5F;
}

#box1 h1 { color: #275157; }
#box1-ing h1 { color: #275157; }

#box1 a { color: #56773D; }
#box1-ing a { color: #56773D; }

#box1 .link1 { color: #FFFFFF; }
#box1-ing .link1 { color: #FFFFFF; }

#box1 .tabs {
    clear: both;
    height: 40px;
    background: url(images/homepage17.jpg) no-repeat right top;
}
#box1-ing .tabs {
    clear: both;
    height: 40px;
    background: url(images/homepage17.jpg) no-repeat;
}

#box1 .tabs ul {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    list-style: none;
    line-height: normal;
}
#box1-ing .tabs ul {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    list-style: none;
    line-height: normal;
}

#box1 .tabs li { float: left; }
#box1-ing .tabs li { float: left; }

#box1 .tabs a {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 132px;
    height: 32px;
    padding: 111px 0px 0px 28px;
    background: url(images/homepage16.jpg) no-repeat left top;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: red;
}
#box1-ing .tabs a {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 132px;
    height: 32px;
    padding: 8px 0px 0px 28px;
    background: url(images/homepage16.jpg) no-repeat left top;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

and thats my html:

```
 <div id="box1">
  <div id="tabs" class="tabs-bottom">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#tabs-1">Nunc tincidunt</a></li>
      <li><a href="#tabs-2">Proin dolor</a></li>
      <li><a href="#tabs-3">Aenean lacinia</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="content"><img src="images/homepage12.jpg" alt="" width="117"  height="117" class="left" />
    <div id="tabs-1">
      <p></p>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-2">
      <p></p>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-3">
      <p></p>
      <p>/p>
    </div>
    <p style="margin-left: 142px; margin-top :10px;"><a href="#" class="link1">Read Full Story</a></p>
        </div>
      </div>                    
    </div>
```

now the problem is that the css doesn't working on the "a" tags, all the rest of the html file getting the css file, just not the tabs names in the tabs div.

the box1-ing tabs are in different page, and the tabs there are working as i need.

the box1-ing html code:

```
<div id="box1-ing">
                    <?php if(in_array($include_file, $home) ){ ?> 
                        <div class="tabs">
                            <ul>
                                <li <?php if($include_file == '') { echo "class='active'";}?>><a href="">User Info</a></li>
                                <li <?php if($include_file == '') { echo "class='active'";}?>><a href="">Inventory</a></li>
                                <li <?php if($include_file == '') { echo "class='active'";}?>><a href="">Company</a></li>
                                <li <?php if($include_file == '') { echo "class='active'";}?>><a href="">Newsletter</a></li>
                                <li <?php if($include_file == '') { echo "class='active'";}?>><a href="">My Account</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    <?php };?>
                    <div class="content">
                        <?php include_once($include_file);?>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: looks fine at http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/yqG47/2/ what is the problem

Comment: where is the `box1-ing` element

Comment: i wrote in the post, the box1-ing is at other page, almost the same i just need different css for those. those tabs are working right.

Comment: can you share the html for the `box1-ing` element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are mixing IDs and classes. Any of the following HTML or CSS changes should target your `<a>` tags.

```
<div id="box1">
  <div class="tabs tabs-bottom">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#tabs-1">Nunc tincidunt</a></li>
      <li><a href="#tabs-2">Proin dolor</a></li>
      <li><a href="#tabs-3">Aenean lacinia</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="content"><img src="images/homepage12.jpg" alt="" width="117"  height="117" class="left" />
      <div id="tabs-1" class="tabs">
        <p></p>
      </div>
      <div id="tabs-2" class="tabs">
        <p></p>
      </div>
      <div id="tabs-3" class="tabs">
        <p></p>
        <p></p>
      </div>
      <p style="margin-left: 142px; margin-top :10px;"><a href="#" class="link1">Read Full Story</a></p>
    </div>
  </div>                    
</div>
```

or

```
#box1 #tabs {
    clear: both;
    height: 40px;
    background: url(images/homepage17.jpg) no-repeat right top;
}

#box1 #tabs ul {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    list-style: none;
    line-height: normal;
}

#box1 #tabs li { float: left; }

#box1 #tabs a {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 132px;
    height: 32px;
    padding: 111px 0px 0px 28px;
    background: url(images/homepage16.jpg) no-repeat left top;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: red;
}
```

or

```
#box1 .tabs-bottom {
    clear: both;
    height: 40px;
    background: url(images/homepage17.jpg) no-repeat right top;
}

#box1 .tabs-bottom ul {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    list-style: none;
    line-height: normal;
}

#box1 .tabs-bottom li { float: left; } 

#box1 .tabs-bottom a {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 132px;
    height: 32px;
    padding: 111px 0px 0px 28px;
    background: url(images/homepage16.jpg) no-repeat left top;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: red;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cf676/2/

Comment: thanks alot, i was thinking thats the problem, changed that alot but no success, thanks

Comment: yea i changed the html but needed to change the jquery as well. thank you alot